# moving menu bar with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menubar

I am designing a site with a menu bar that starts with a relative position in a header element. Its distance from the top in pixels is 300.  I want to make a javascript function that changes the position to fixed and the top to 0 when i scroll on the page below 300 pixels. This is so that the menu bar will always be at the top of the screen when navigating down.  Does anyone have a good method of doing this?  I thought of maybe doing some type of function that checks after a set timer for like 10 ms and checking the window.pageYoffset.  This cant be the best method.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Browsers support subscribing callbacks to be triggered when the window scrolls: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Monitor the window's `scroll` event:](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    if ($('body').scrollTop()>300) {
        $('#header').css('position','fixed');
    } else {
        $('#header').css('position','relative');
    }
});
```

Slightly optimized:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    $('#header').css('position', ($('body').scrollTop()>300) ? 'fixed' : 'relative');
    }
});
```